# Spring Data Сохранение связей в модели

Tags: java, spring-data

Прошу и помощи, замучался...
Есть три модели:
`RssCategory:`

```
@Entity(name = "RssCategory")
@Table(name = "rss_category")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"rssFeeds"})
public class RssCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "rss_feed_category",
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "feed_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    public Set<RssFeed> rssFeeds = new LinkedHashSet<RssFeed>();
}
```

`RssFeed:`

```
@Entity(name = "RssFeed")
@Table(name = "rss_feed")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"rssChannel"})
public class RssFeed {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column
  private Integer id;

//  @Id
  @Column(unique = true)
  @Index(name = "title_index")
  private String title;

  @Column
  @URL
  private String link;

  @Column
  private String description;

  @Column
  private String content;

  @Column
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date pubDate;

  @Column
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date updateDate;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "channelId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private RssChannel rssChannel;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "rssFeeds")
  private Set<RssCategory> rssCategories = new LinkedHashSet<RssCategory>();
}
```

`RssChannel:`

```
@Entity(name = "RssChannel")
@Table(name = "rss_channel",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"link"}))
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"feeds"})
public class RssChannel implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String title;

  @Column(unique = true)
  @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL
  private String link;

  @Column
  @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.URL
  private String image;

  @Column
  private String description;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rssChannel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<RssFeed> feeds = new LinkedHashSet<RssFeed>();
}
```

Работаю с spring-data-jpa. Вообщем воопрос. Вот создал я RssChannel. Как мне потом добавить туда еще новостей `RssFeed` и к новостям через связь M2M добавить категории? Пример не сложные, если можно. Просто периодически вылетают три ошибки:

1. `ERROR: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; UK_2FUC9Y0WV1393BSAISKSKCUYY table: RSS_CATEGORY`
2. `integrity constraint violation foreign key no parent`
3. `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role, no session or session was closed`

Как я добавляю RssChannel, тут проблем нету, все хорошо:

```
@Override
  public RssChannel add(String link) throws IOException, FeedException {
    RssChannel rssChannel = new RssChannel();
    URL feedUrl = new URL(link);
    SyndFeedInput input = new SyndFeedInput();
    SyndFeed feed = input.build(new XmlReader(feedUrl));
    SyndImage image = feed.getImage();
    if (image != null)
      rssChannel.setImage(feed.getImage().getLink());
    rssChannel.setLink(link);
    rssChannel.setTitle(feed.getTitle());
    rssChannelDAO.save(rssChannel);
    return rssChannel;

  }
```

Добавление RssFeed и RssCategory:

```
public Message<RssFeed> transform(SyndEntry syndEntry, @Header("BASE_URL") URL url) {
    // Возвращает запись из БД
    RssChannel channel = rssChannelService.get(url.toString());
    RssFeed rssFeed = new RssFeed();
    rssFeed.setTitle(syndEntry.getTitle());
    rssFeed.setPubDate(syndEntry.getPublishedDate());
    rssFeed.setLink(syndEntry.getLink());
    rssFeed.setUpdatedDate(syndEntry.getUpdatedDate());
    SyndContent description = syndEntry.getDescription();
    if(description != null)
      rssFeed.setDescription(description.getValue());
    List contents = syndEntry.getContents();
    if(contents != null && contents.size() > 0)
      rssFeed.setContent(((SyndContent) contents.get(0)).getValue());
    List<SyndCategory> categories = syndEntry.getCategories();
    for(SyndCategory category: categories) {
      RssCategory rssCategory = new RssCategory();
      rssCategory.setTitle(category.getName());
      rssCategoryService.findOrCreate(rssCategory);
      rssCategory.getRssFeeds().add(rssFeed);
      rssFeed.getRssCategories().add(rssCategory);
    }
    // Просто обычный вызов у JpaRepository save()
    rssChannelService.update(channel);
    rssFeed.setRssChannel(channel);
    // Вот тут выскакивает третья ошибка
    channel.getFeeds().add(rssFeed);
    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(rssFeed).build();
  }
```

Comment: 1 - у вас стоит уникальный индекс на поле, а вы пытаетесь добавить запись с еще одним таким названием; 2 - насколько понимаю, это из-за неправильного управления CASCADE: движок пытается сначала добавить связанные сущности, а этого нельзя сделать из-за существующего foreign key.

Comment: Хорошо, первую и вторую проблему я прекрасно понимаю, как можно их обойти? 1 - что-нибудь типо saveOrUpdate. Не подскажите у JpaRepository  нету ничего?
2 - я безпонятие чего она там творит...

Comment: Их не нужно обходить, их нужно решать. По cascade не подскажу, потому что сам до сих пор не нашел время разобраться, по JPARepository saveOrUpdate точно не будет, но вы же легко можете сначала поробовать найти такую запись, и только потом добавить (все равно держа catch на случай, если второй поток таки успел прорваться и создать такую запись).

Comment: Так, ну первая проблема решилась, очевидным образом. А вот вторая... Не хочет решаться никак... Постоянно пишет: `ERROR: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no parent; FK_4UF00P0LP08KCHPWMMST2M4WB table: RSS_FEED`

Comment: Так, поправил, теперь сохраняется связка RssChannel - RssFeed. т.е. с foreign key я разобрался, но к сожалению с Many to many разобратся не могу... Пишет, что `rg.hibernate.PersistentObjectException detached entity passed to persist: RssCategory`